# Winappdriver-python how can I switch and access another window

Tags: python, selenium, appium, winappdriver

I use winappdriver with python to automate my windows application. The application opens a sub-window that i need to access/validate. I tried some ways but could not get it working. Another scenario is the application opens a windows file-save dialog where I am unable to send_keys and hit save button.

Could someone please help? Is there some code i need to use to switch to new window?

I am able to launch the application and access the main application window without issues.
My application launch code looks like this

import pytest
from appium import webdriver
webdriver.remote(command_executor='http://localhost:4723", desired_capabilities={"app":<>})

When I try to switch to the new window using the below code.

windows = self.driver.window_handles()
self.driver.switch_to_window(windows[0])

I get error ‘Webdriver object has no attribute ‘w3c’

Comment: With appium webdriver is there any specific capabilities I need to set up to be able to switch windows in my desktop application ? Please help if you have suggestions

Comment: Got it working , sharing here if it helps someone. Use driver.window_handles [and not driver.window_handles()]. I also set w3c attribute as driver.w3c = False